# Units of Quantum States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, conventions, units, dimensional-analysis

I've been taught that a continuous quantum state $ | \psi \rangle $ is unit-less, while the (improper) kets $ | x \rangle $ have units of $1/\sqrt{length}$. I've seen a lot of relations that "force" the units to take on these forms, but that doesn't impart any intuition as to why a state that's comprised of a series of an infinite number of kets doesn't have the same units as the kets

Comment: An integral with dimensionful coefficietns dictated by the integration measure? $|\psi\rangle=\int dx ~ \psi(x) |x\rangle$ forces dimensions pegged on those   of the wavefunction *ψ*. Can you *imagine* any consistent alternative?

Answer (score 2):

That $|\psi\rangle$ is dimensionless follows directly from $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$. Also, the fact that a unit operator can be written as $\hat{I} = \int |x\rangle\langle x|\, d x$ implies that $|x\rangle$ has units of $L^{-1/2}$. This goes for any basis. Whenever $\hat{I}$ in a basis contains an integral over some coordinates that have units $U$, the corresponding basis vectors will have units of $U^{-1/2}$ so that the result is dimensionless.

If your statement was true, then I could also use plane waves as basis, and say that now $|\psi\rangle$ is comprised of vectors that have unit $L^{1/2}$, thus $|\psi\rangle$ must also have units $L^{1/2}$.

The only way this is consistent is - as mentioned in a comment - for the coefficients to have the inverse unit of the basis, thus making $|\psi\rangle$ dimensionless.